# Run time error over conditional formatting in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, conditional-formatting

So this was working, highlighting the cells to the right of the checkaddress value. Now it isn't and I cant figure out why. It gives the error "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument". The error is in the first .Add statement, but commented it out, all the .Add statements error.

```
Sub Highlight4()

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).row Step 2

    If Cells(i, 4) = "Metric" Then
        For j = 1 To 15

        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Range(Cells(i, j * 4 + 2), Cells(i + 1, j * 4 + 4))

        Dim checkAddress As String
        checkAddress = Cells(i, j * 4 + 1).Address

        With r.FormatConditions
            .Delete

            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & checkAddress & " = 0"
            .Item(.Count).Interior.Color = rgbRed

            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & checkAddress & " = 15"
            .Item(.Count).Interior.Color = rgbGold

            .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & checkAddress & " = 25"
            .Item(.Count).Interior.Color = rgbGreen
        End With

        Next j
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What row gives the error?

Comment: .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & checkAddress & " = 0"

Comment: What is the value of `checkAddress` when it fails?  Is it always the same?

Comment: What is your formula supposed to look like? I imagine it's not what you expect with `"=" & checkAddress & " = 0"` - that looks like your trying to assign an address to be equal to 0 - but prefacing it with "=" sign. Doesn't make sense to me - what is it supposed to do?

Comment: checkaddress holds the value In the location I gave it, so it differs in each column based on the for loop.. that's not the issue and its conditional formatting so if checkaddress value is 0, then turn the cell red, if its 15, turn the cell yellow, etc. The check address cell location will hold a value prior to running this sub

Comment: checkaddress holds $E$33 but that's correct and I put r as lowercase

Comment: Your code works for me. Perhaps, close and restart excel?

Comment: @siddharthRout can I ask what version of excel you are using? I had 2007 when I built this and it worked, and then I switched to 2013 recently. Do you think that could be an issue?

Comment: If  Excel is running in R1C1 Formula mode then you will get the error. Verify it is not in R1C1 mode

Comment: @siddharthrout ah you fixed it thank you

Comment: Awesome :) Didn't see your comment. I was posting an answer lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You are getting that error because Excel is running in `R1C1` mode. Switch it off and it will be fine :)

1. Click on `File | Options | Formulas`
2. Un check `R1C1 Reference Style`

[image]